# Accessing $location in a service

Tags: angularjs

Can $location be accessed inside of a service like this? No matter what I do $location comes up as undefined. Thank you in advance for the help.

```
myApp.service 'Session', ['$location', ($location)->
  class Session

    user: (data) ->
      @_user = data if data
      @_user


    logout: ->
      @_user = null
      $location.path '/'

]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Problem is the way CoffeeScript translates to JavaScript. The assignment of the class is being returned, where you'll want to return an instance of the class.

Change to

```
myApp.service 'Session', ['$location', ($location)->
  class Session

    user: (data) ->
      @_user = data if data
      @_user


    logout: ->
      @_user = null
      $location.path '/'

  return new Session()

]
```

And it should work.